# Getting "failed to find request token in session" while trying to integrate linkedin login via passport linkedin

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting the following error while trying to integrate linkedin login via passport linkedin:

> Error: Failed to find request token in session    at
>   Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\passport-linkedin\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:142:54)
>   at Strategy.authenticate
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\passport-linkedin\lib\strategy.js:118:40)
>   at attempt
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:348:16)
>   at authenticate
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:349:7)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at
>   C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>   at next
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>   at
>   C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\connect-flash\lib\flash.js:21:5 
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>   at
>   C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\jobninja\facebookauth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12).

Here is my code

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({

        consumerKey     : configAuth.linkedinAuth.clientID,
        consumerSecret  : configAuth.linkedinAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.linkedinAuth.callbackURL,

    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        // make the code asynchronous
        // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Linkedin
        process.nextTick(function() {

            // try to find the user based on their linkedin id
            User.findOne({ 'linkedin.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (user) {

                    // if a user is found, log them in
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
                    var newUser          = new User();

                    // set all of the relevant information
                    newUser.linkedin.id    = profile.id;
                    newUser.linkedin.token = token;
                    newUser.linkedin.name  = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.linkedin.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }));
```

Can anyone figure out the error and help?

Answer (score 0):

Does your callback url is the same as the initiaiting host url?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the callback url was same that's why the code was not working. I had "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/linkedin/callback" as my callback url in both the places. I change the callback url to 'http://localhost:8080/auth/linkedin/callback' in my auth.js file and the above error was removed. But now I am facing this error : 

newUser.linkedin.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

Type error: cannot read property 0 of undefined.

Any suggestions.

Comment: please show more code, will be good as a new question because this is another topic, And if my answer was good for you please accept it.